# How to pass by value function loop using array address parameter in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am currently experimenting with the fun ways you can loop with C.

I declared an array locally, and printed that out using a pointer to the address &array for loop.

I was trying out two different approaches:

1. Passing an array to this for within the same scope.
2. Passing an array by value to a function to loop.

The output should be the same, but the latter seems to print exactly 4 more value:address elements out of bounds from the array.

N.B : No this is not 'industry' standard way of doing things, i'm just curious about accessing memory here.

1st approach:

```
int main()
{  

  int T[] = {1, 2, 3, 8}; // declare and init.

  for(int * p = T; p < *(&T+1); p++)
  {
    printf("%d \t: %x\n", *p, p);
  }

}
```

Output:

```
1       : eda32920
2       : eda32924
3       : eda32928
8       : eda3292c
```

2nd approach: (different output than expected)

```
void loop(int T[])
{

  for(int * p = T; p < *(&T+1); p++)
  {
    printf("%d \t: %x\n", *p, p);
  }

}

int main()
{
  int T[] = {1, 2, 3, 8}; // declare and init.

  loop(T);

}
```

Output:

```
1       : e3929920
2       : e3929924
3       : e3929928
8       : e392992c
-476931752      : e3929930
32766   : e3929934
-1358561188     : e3929938
2041695417      : e392993c
```

How and why does passing by affect the condition statement of this for loop, and print out exactly 4 more elements?

Comment: You have undefined behavior in both the cases. Anything can happen.

Comment: Thanks @kiranBiradar, but there's no deeper explanation other than that?

Comment: The behavior of `*(&T+1)` is not defined by the C standard because it attempts to produce an object that does not exist. `&T+1` calculates the address just beyond the end of `T`, and this is explicitly allowed by the C standard as a special case of address arithmetic. However, it does not point to any defined object. The result of the `*` operator is an lvalue for the object its operand points to, but, when the operand does not point to an object, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: It is weird the second set of code printed eight lines. `&T` produces the address of the parameter, and `&T+1` is just beyond that. Normally, that is someplace on the stack and is below the array `T` defined in `main`. In which case, a direct (taking the code literally with no optimization) execution of `for(int * p = T; p < *(&T+1); p++)` would stop immediately, as `T` is at a higher address than `*(&T+1)`, so the `<` is false. It could be interesting to look at the assembly for clues about how the compiler interpreted this. What compiler and version did you use? What command-line switches?

Comment: Incidentally, when printing pointers, convert them to `(void *)` and use `%p`, as in `printf("%d \t: %p\n", *p, (void *) p);`. Using `%x` is incorrect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  : SPECS: 
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/

Comment: No command line args, just the usual: clang loop.c -o loop

Comment: Ah, what is happening is that `&T` is the address of the parameter, and `&T+1` is just beyond that. That happens to be where the `loop` routine saved the previous frame pointer. So `*(&T+1)` is the saved frame pointer, meaning it is the frame pointer of `main`, so it points to the top of the local data of `main`. Thus, the loop iterates from where `T` is in that data until the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

In the second code snippet that is when an array is passed to a function you are dealing with a pointer instead of the array, because when an array is passed by value it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. And the compiler adjusts a parameter having an array type to pointer to the element type.

So the function declaration in fact looks the following way

```
void loop(int *T )
{

  for(int * p = T; p < *(&T+1); p++)
  {
    printf("%d \t: %x\n", *p, p);
  }

}
```

So as the `sizeof( int * )` is equal to either 4 or 8 (depending on used system) then the expression

```
*(&T+1)
```

does not points to the memory after the last element of the array pointed to by the expression `&T`.

Comment: ! Thanks! Is there any reading you would recommend to find out more about this? Id be curious about how you learned about undefined behaviours in C..

Comment: @WilliamMorris The best resource is the C Standard.:)

Comment: @WilliamMorris http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3 and http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2 - that's the latest public draft of C11 revision. Unfortunately no one has made a anchor-linkable version of the C18 yet

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks. It is useful references.

Comment: Is there an amendment to the syntax one can make to this the condition *(&T+1) that utilises the size of the array too as an additional argument from the function? Or would you say that *(&T+1) condition is not applicable with function arguments?

Comment: @Will It is not applicable because sizeof( &T ) is either 4 or 8 depending on used system.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an array as an argument in C function what's really passed is pointer to the beginning of that array so the function doesn't know the actual size of that array that's why those extra garbage values are getting printed. You need to pass an extra argument "size" along with the array argument you are passing.

Comment: Cool. So moral of the story is, don't try to second guess the size of an array. Thanks for the heads up.